# jQuery .height() wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to slope the edge of a div and as the page should be responsive the slope needs to adjust. However, the angle should always be the same on all screen sizes which I am already archieving. My problem is that for some reason the $('#slope').height() is not always returning the correct height and instead it is kind of glitching when I am resizing the window or switching the tab.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="block">
        <div id="content">
          Some content<<br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit sint culpa, dolor quaerat autem repellendus, doloremque molestiae, natus ut veritatis eius deserunt mollitia. Eaque ex facilis nobis obcaecati dolorem odio veniam laudantium nemo voluptates voluptas nulla ducimus officia quod maiores corporis hic nisi incidunt aliquid fugiat tenetur at, labore earum. Sapiente perspiciatis, laudantium consectetur sed omnis porro quasi quae. Neque voluptatem, praesentium mollitia ad cumque voluptates ipsa dolores velit beatae odio veniam, voluptatum atque repellat. Minus perferendis, natus accusantium! Sunt architecto provident error commodi. Provident dolorum praesentium quis fuga saepe odio fugiat reiciendis laborum sed at facilis natus facere, dignissimos repellendus. Numquam fugiat consectetur deleniti tempora quibusdam distinctio nulla sequi voluptate inventore voluptas cupiditate eaque soluta neque optio rem vel autem adipisci id fuga sapiente voluptates harum, eius est qui. Asperiores molestiae recusandae cum non sint deserunt nisi aliquid dicta obcaecati ut repellat tenetur laudantium eaque, amet praesentium numquam laboriosam, beatae vitae vel. Tenetur recusandae dicta voluptate aperiam architecto saepe provident odit deleniti possimus consequatur libero voluptas sequi officia minima perspiciatis repellendus voluptates nostrum fugit voluptatem, vero. Minima, tempora vero dicta provident, ducimus nobis quibusdam nam blanditiis eligendi architecto pariatur, enim ut eos reiciendis quisquam aut, eum at porro esse!
        </div>
        <div id="slope">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

#block {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#slope {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid #fff;
  border-left: solid green;
  border-width: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {


updateSize();


  $(window).resize(function() {
    updateSize();
  });
});

function updateSize() {
  $('#slope').css('border-width', '0 0 ' + $('#slope').height() + 'px ' + $('#slope').height()/6 + 'px');
}
```

[my Code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ianbeu/Ly4vn3h6/37/)

You can reproduce the bug by resizing your window. The slope should always go from the top right corner down with an angle of 10°

Comment: Is it falling into sub-pixel territory by any chance? You may need to `Math.floor()` the value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `.height` periodically returns a wrong value, but I would suggest using `.outerHeight` instead, as it returns correct height.